# Python Challenge Level 3

Tags: python

I know many others have asked about this problem, but wanted to see if anyone would be kind enough to offer some feedback on my code and why it isn't working. For those unfamiliar with the problem, I'm using a massive string and trying to identify a lower case letter surrounded on both sides by exactly three uppercase letters (so the fourth character on each side would be lowercase). The weird thing is, my code sometimes works on shorter strings, and then randomly stops working. But it never works on the full string (probably 10,000+ characters). OK, here's the code:

```
def python_challenge_3(code):
 for letter in code[3:-3]:
    if letter.islower():
        i = code.index(letter)
        if code[i-3:i].isupper() and code[i-4].islower() and code[i+1:i+4].isupper() and code[i+4].islower():
            return code[i-3:i+4]
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.index()` returns the first index matching that letter, instead use `enumerate()` to get the index

Comment: Do not use `.index()`, it gives you the FIRST index, not the current index. The 'random' part you are missing is characters that appear more than once.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm having trouble knowing where to insert (or swap out with) `enumerate()`. Can you show an example of how I should modify? Thanks!

Comment: @MattK. Something like `for i, letter in enumerate(code[3:-3], 3):`; then you don't need to define `i` after

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract the character by the condition you specified. The code may look something like this:

```
import re

def extract(txt: str) -> list:
    return re.findall(r'[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z]{1})[A-Z]{3}[a-z]', txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract('abCDEfGHIjklMNOpQRStUVwXYz'))
```

This prints out all the matches:

```
>>> ['f', 'p']
```